# How to highlight current menu in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Please see the site http://tourbazaar.co.in
You can see that when i hover it chages to offwhite color.
I want to retain that color for the current page selected.
How to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add a style to the class `current_page_item`

```
li.current_page_item {
    background-color: #HEXVALUE
}
```

Comment: Another thing is that i also want to change the text color to black i am using this li.current_page_item {
    background-color: #efefef;
 color:#000;
} But the text color not changed to black

Comment: try `li.current_page_item a { color: #000; }`

Comment: It worked by simply using 

    li.current_page_item a {   background-color: #efefef;
     color: #000 !important; }


!important is the key which after declaring the problem solved.
Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

It worked by simply using

```
li.current_page_item a {   background-color: #efefef;
    color: #000 !important; }
```

!important is the key